# Проблема с frameless window в Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, desktop, electron

При создании frameless window в электроне нужно создать меню для свертывания/развертывания/закрытия окна:
[image: меню]
Но вот в чем проблема: я никак не могу найти в документации Electron метод "свернуть окно". Есть метод `BrowserWindow.hide()`, но он полностью его скрывает, вместе с иконкой в таскбаре.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

метод называется `minimize()`, см. [Electron API Reference](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md)